# Exposing both parent and child entities as REST repositories in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a parent child entity configured in a Spring Date REST repository. The parent looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DPST_DTL")
public class Deposit {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "deposit", orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Instrument> instrumentList = new ArrayList<Instrument>();
}
```

The child looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTR_DTL")
public class Instrument {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DPST_ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Deposit deposit;
}
```

I have defined a RepositoryRestresource for Deposit as follows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "deposit", path = "deposit")
public interface DepositRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Deposit, Long>{

}
```

and a same one for Instrument as follows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "instrument", path = "instrument")
public interface InstrumentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Instrument, Long>{

}
```

If I attempt to POST the parent with some child records, I get a message like below: 
         "message": "Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type [com.XXX.irh.insprc.instrument.Instrument] for value 'countryCode'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI countryCode. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable."
   },

"countryCode" happens to be the first field in the child JSON

If I query a the parent with some children, teh resulting JSON does not expant the children and just display a link like this:
"instrumentList": {"href": "http://localhost:9090/deposit/8/instrumentList"}

However if I mark the child repository with exported=false, I am able to get past this issue. But the child entity cannot be exposed via a REST API.

Question is:

Is there anyway I can expose basic CRUD functionalities for both parent and child entities, without writing custom controllers etc.?

I understand that as per DDD best practices my parent is an aggregate that should be exposed via a REST Repository, but I do have some use cases unfortunately where I need independent CRUD functionality for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections):

```
@Projection(name = "withInstruments", types = Person.class)
public interface WithInstruments {

   @Value("#{target.depositName}")
   String getDepositName();

   List<Instrument> getInstrumentList();  
}
```

Then you can GET your entities together:

```
GET /deposits?projection=withInstruments
{
   "depositName": "deposit1",
   "instrumentList": [
       {
           "intrumentName": "instrument1",
       },
       {
           "intrumentName": "instrument1",
       }
   ]
}
```

Additional [info](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1173?focusedCommentId=153855&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-153855)